# Using ES6 Generator functions with SailsJS

Tags: node.js, sails.js, ecmascript-6

I love generators in nodejs. They help nodejs look more like server-side code. I'm trying to use generators with my Sails app. This is my controller and it works when I visit 'get /hi':

```
/**
 * FooController
 *
 * @description :: Server-side logic for managing foos
 * @help        :: See http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/concepts/Controllers
 */

module.exports = {
  hi: function (req, res){
    return res.send("Hi there!");
  }
};
```

However when I change that hi action to a generator function...

```
module.exports = {
  hi: function* (req, res){
    return res.send("Hi there!");
  }
};
```

this action never gets to return the response. Like it's waiting for something. How does one utilize ES6 generators within SailsJS controllers and in-fact all of Sails?

Comment: **Why** would you want to do this? Now you've got a function that returns a generator (which is *not magic*!) instead of a function that calls `res.send` - of course it behaves differently.

Comment: It can be done, with a little variation of what you've tried, check out my answer below :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sails expects a regular function here, not a generator. Maybe you could take a look at [co](https://www.npmjs.com/package/co), not sure it would really help with Sails though. If you really want to use generators, you should probably try [Koa](http://koajs.com/), which has [several frameworks](https://github.com/koajs/koa/wiki#frameworks) based on it

Comment: Just an update on this:  While Sails and Waterline don't encourage the low-level use of ES generators, they do strongly encourage the use of `await`.  As a rule of thumb: "if it supports .exec(), then it's a Deferred, so it also supports `await`, + other convenience methods like .toPromise(), .intercept() and .tolerate()"   (More on that: http://npmjs.com/package/parley)

Answer (score 3):

**You can use it**, in fact it'll be great if we all use this style, it adds a lot of readability and flexibility in your code (no more callback-hell), **but that is not the way to use it**.

As @Cohars stated, **sails expect a function as controller actions**, you can't pass a generator like in Koa, but that does not prevent you from using them, the thing is that **a generator by itself is very useless, you need a function that calls it and iterates it** and i believe koa does this for you at framework level, but you have some options available to you at library level, like [co](https://www.npmjs.com/package/co) or [yortus/asyncawait/](https://github.com/yortus/asyncawait/) which is what i use because node-fibers implemented as functions are way more flexible than es6 generators (though they are almost the same) and i'll show you why in a sec.

So here is how you use it:

First `npm install co` and require it in your controller, or add it as a global in config/bootstrap.js since you will be using it a lot. Once you are done with it, you can use it in your controllers.

```
module.exports = {
  hi: function(req, res){
    co(function* (){
      // And you can use it with your models calls like this
      let user = yield User.findOne(req.param('id'))
      return res.send("Hi there" + user.name + "!");
    })
  }
};
```

That's it

Now if you rather use **async/await**, its pretty similar, it goes like this:

```
module.exports = {
  hi: function(req, res){
    async(function(){
      // Since await is a function, you can access properties
      // of the returned values like this which is nice to
      // access object properties or array indices
      let userName = await(User.findOne(req.param('id'))).name
      return res.send("Hi there" + userName + "!");
    })();
  }
};
```

There is a **caveat** though, if you call other methods of you controller via `this`, remember that they will refer to the generator fn or the passed regular fn if you use async/await, so be sure to save its context, or since you are already using es6 syntax, you can use fat arrows with async/await, unfortunately not with co, since there is not fat arrow version of generators (..yet?)

So it'll be like this:

```
module.exports = {
  hi: function(req, res){
    async(() => {
      let params = this._parseParams(req);
      let userName = await(User.findOne(params.id)).name
      return res.send("Hi there" + userName + "!");
    })();
  },
  _parseParams: function(req){
    let params = req.allParams()
    // Do some parsing here...
    return params
  }

};
```

I've been using the second method for months now, and works perfectly, i've   tried with co too and works as well, i just liked more the async/await module (and is supposed to be a little bit faster) and its a perfect match if you are using coffeescript since your sintax will be like `do async => await User.find()`

**UPDATE:**

I've created a wrapper that you can use if you use yortus async/await or check the source code and modify it to work with co or something else if you wish.

Here is the link https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-handler, is in alpha but i'm using on my own apps and works as expected, if not submit an issue.

With that the las example would look like this:

```
module.exports = {
    hi: asyncHandler((req, res)->{
      let params = this._parseParams(req);
      let userName = await(User.findOne(params.id)).name
      return res.send("Hi there" + userName + "!");
    }),
    _parseParams: function(req){
      let params = req.allParams()
      // Do some parsing here...
      return params
    }
};
```

With this handler you get the extra benefit of having async/promise errors to propagate correctly on sails if they are not caught by a try/catch

Answer (score 0):

The way I am doing it is like this:

```js
const Promise = require('bluebird');

module.exports = {
  hi: Promise.coroutine(function* (req, res) {
    let id = req.params('id'),
        userName;
    try {
      userName = yield User.findOne(id).name;
    }
    catch (e) {
      sails.log.error(e);
      return res.serverError(e.message);
    }

    return res.ok(`Hi there ${userName}!`);
  })
}
```

Works great. You just need to ensure any functions you call from your controllers return promises.

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your `bootstrap.js`, and every thing work like a charm!

```
var _ = require('lodash');
var coExpress = require('co-express');

sails.modules.loadControllers(function (err, modules) {
  if (err) {
    return callback(err);
  }
  sails.controllers = _.merge(sails.controllers, modules);

  // hacking every action of all controllers
  _.each(sails.controllers, function(controller, controllerId) {
    _.each(controller, function(action, actionId) {
      actionId = actionId.toLowerCase();
      console.log('hacking route:', controllerId, actionId);
      // co.wrap，generator => callback
      action = coExpress(action);
      sails.hooks.controllers.middleware[controllerId][actionId] = action;
    });
  });
  // reload routes
  sails.router.load(function () {
    // reload blueprints
    sails.hooks.blueprints.initialize(function () {
      sails.hooks.blueprints.extendControllerMiddleware();
      sails.hooks.blueprints.bindShadowRoutes();
      callback();
    });
  });
});
```